# How does this lambda function work in Razor pages tutorial for ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lambda, razor-pages

I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio-code) for ASP.NET Core 2.2 and in their `ConfigureServices` they have the following lambda function.

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

I have read up on lambda functions in C# but want to make sure I have the following right:

1. The options variable that is sent in while have its CheckConsentNeeded set to true IN THIS SCOPE ONLY.
2. It does the changes in the options => lambda then sends in the modified version of options into the Configure function.

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. You can think of this as an anonymous function that's returning your modified settings of the `CookiePolicyOptions` class

Answer (score 2):

I'll speak directly to the two assertions first.

> 1. The `options` <s>variable</s> parameter that is <s>sent</s> passed in <s>while</s> will have its `CheckConsentNeeded` set to true IN THIS SCOPE ONLY.

It *happens* "in this scope only" but that wording is misleading because the property value doesn't revert at some later point.  What *happens* in Vegas only (this scope) doesn't *stay* in Vegas only, because...

> 2. It does the changes in the `options =>` lambda then sends in the modified version of options into the Configure function.

Yes, it *makes the changes* there, but it doesn't "send" the object anywhere.  It's like if I (the middleware) asked you (your application) for your autograph (desired cookie settings) and held the autograph book (`options`) for you while you signed it (modified its properties).

The middleware pipeline doesn't relinquish control of the object it created and passed in, nor does it receive a new object upon return.  Resuming the metaphor, I don't get a new autograph book with your autograph in it and lose the original one with all the other autographs (other property changes) I had.

In theory, the same instance could be passed to multiple delegates, provided by both you and any middlewares you're using that need specific settings, each changing properties as needed.  In theory, anyway.  I can't say if that ever happens in the real world but given the way it's structured, it seems possible.

---

**Additional Details**

What you're doing there is providing a configuration function *to be called later* by the middleware pipeline.  In order to see things from a different perspective, let's refactor it to a point of being almost absurdly verbose:

```
// In your 'ConfigureServices' method:
Action<CookiePolicyOptions> myCookieConfigurator = MyCookiePolicyOptionsConfigurationMethod;

services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(myCookieConfigurator);
```

Elsewhere in that class:

```
private void MyCookiePolicyOptionsConfigurationMethod(CookiePolicyOptions options)
{
    Func<HttpContext, bool> myCheckConsentNeeded = MyCheckConsentNeededMethod;

    options.CheckConsentNeeded = myCheckConsentNeeded;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
}

private bool MyCheckConsentNeededMethod(HttpContext context)
{
    return true;
}
```

This is essentially what the C# compiler does to lambdas when there's no context capture involved, except it generates methods with names you can't possibly call directly in C# code.  (When there's context capture involved, there's more to it.)

At some point, possibly long after `Configure` and your `ConfigureServices` have both returned, the middleware pipeline creates a `CookiePolicyOptions` instance and passes it to your lambda function, which then sets the options you specify.

```
// Somewhere in the middleware (although a bit more involved than this).

CookiePolicyOptions cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions();
that_guys_myCookieConfigurator_delegate(cookiePolicyOptions);
// now store 'cookiePolicyOptions' for middleware to use
```

So how does the cookie middleware use the object that was just created and configured?

If a middleware takes a `CookiePolicyOptions` parameter, that object gets injected into the call to its `Configure` method (not to be confused with yours by the same name in Startup.cs).  The middleware then uses that object's properties to configure its behavior.  Those properties' values have persisted long past the context in which they were assigned.